# How to get the correct object when using search controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am using searchdisplaycontroller,I have a table view above that  i have a search bar... the table view displays a list of object names.. for example if i have an json object like

```
json :{
name: testname;
age:12;
maths:50;
english:56;
science:45;
},
{
// list of similar json objects
}
```

i have displayed only name in table row using `cell.name.text = [json valueforKey :@"name"];`

when i dont search anything i can get the whole object when ever user presses the any row by writing

```
[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

My problem is when i search the table i am not getting the correct object at index... for example i search something in the search bar the it displays rows with relevant objects. when i use the same `[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`  wrong index objects gets assigned pls help here is my code

```
-(void)filtercontentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchtext scope:(NSString *)scope{



NSPredicate *resultpredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [cd] %@",searchtext];
    searchList=[[searchDataArray valueForKey:@"SubjectDescription" ] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultpredicate];




    NSLog(@"searchlist %@",searchList );
}



-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString{


    [self filtercontentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles ] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;

}
```

//This is didselectrowAtindex code...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"selected");
  //  if ([numberOfTouchesString isEqualToString:@"One"])
 //   {


       NSArray *selected = [searchDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(selectedSubject:)])


        {
            if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){


                if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]){

                    NSLog(@"searchlist %@",searchList);
                 indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
                    id searchResult = [searchList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                    int indexForResult = [json indexOfObject:searchResult];
                    NSLog(@"indexpath%d " , indexForResult);

                     searchAppDelObj.didselectjsondata=[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//storing that json data in AppDelegate object



                    _serachStr = [searchList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



                    //searchAppDelObj.valuePass=(NSArray *)_serachStr;
                      NSLog(@"   searchAppDelObj.valuePass %@",(NSArray *)_serachStr);
                      //[self.delegate selectedSubject:self];

                }

            }
            else
            {
                LearningSearchCell *cell = (LearningSearchCell *)[self.learningSearchTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                NSString *cellText = cell.subjectNameLabel.text;

                searchAppDelObj.didselectstring=cellText;

                searchAppDelObj.didSelectArray=[searchDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                NSLog(@"appobjarray %@",searchAppDelObj.didSelectArray);

                NSLog(@"AppObj.didselectstring %@",searchAppDelObj.didselectstring);
                //searchAppDelObj.valuePass=selected;
                //[self.delegate selectedSubject:self];
                            }

            if (-[_comparestr isEqualToString:@"search"]) {
                searchAppDelObj.valuePass=(NSArray *)_serachStr;
                NSLog(@"   searchAppDelObj.valuePass %@",(NSArray *)_serachStr);
                [self.delegate selectedSubject:self];
            }else{
                NSLog(@"AppObj.didselectstring %@",searchAppDelObj.didselectstring);
                searchAppDelObj.valuePass=selected;
                [self.delegate selectedSubject:self];
            }
            [self.revealViewController revealToggleAnimated:YES];



        }

    }
```

//Here is CellForRowAtindexpath code.........

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"learningSearchCellIdentifier";
    LearningSearchCell *cell = [self.learningSearchTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier ];

    if ((tableView==self.learningSearchTableView)==YES)
    {


        cell.subjectNameLabel.text=[[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"];
        //subjectString=cell.subjectLabel.text;


        cell.teacherNameLabel.text=[[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"age"];


        cell.subjecDataAndSessionLabel.text=[[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"maths"];

        NSNumber *test  =[[searchDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Cohort"];
        NSString *myString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",test];

        cell.chorotLabel.text=myString;




    }

    else if (tableView==self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

        cell.subjectNameLabel.text=[searchList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"indexpath %d",indexPath.row);

        cell.teacherNameLabel.text=[[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"age"];


         cell.subjecDataAndSessionLabel.text=[[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"maths"];

        NSNumber *test  =[[searchDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"english"];
        NSString *myString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",test];

        cell.chorotLabel.text=myString;



    }

    else{

        cell.subjectNameLabel.text=[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Send the code in detail, so that I can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this will help you

As I understood that you want only those name which set of characters contain in your search bar,

1. first use `NSMutableArray *nameJson` to add your all the name from json.
   and Use `NSArray *nameShowing`

   `_nameShowing = _nameJson`;

   and reload the tableview

uptill now you have your all your name in your table view , and now you  search particular name

```
2.    - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
    {
        self.nameShowing = nil;
        self.nameShowing = [[NSArray alloc]init]; 
         NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains %@", self.searchbar.text];

        self.nameShowing  = [self.nameJson filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
        if(([self.searchbar.text  isEqual:@""]))
        {
            self.nameShowing = self.nameJson;
        }


        [self.tblView reloadData];
    }
```